# How would I cite this pdf short story?

Tags: mla

How would I cite [this](https://www.tcdsb.org/schools/bishopmarroccothomasmerton/literacy/Lists/Resources/Attachments/17/OnTheSidewalkBleeding_Reading_Questions.pdf) pdf short story in MLA format?

MLA provides the following template for ebooks, but is a pdf version of a book really an ebook? Also, in this case, who is the publisher of the book?

```
Lastname, F. M. (Year). Title of book [eBook edition]. Publisher. URL
```

Comment: Your url is on a website owned by the Toronto Catholic District School Board. But probably they are not the copyright holder of this work. It would be better to track down the original source of the work and cite that.

Comment: The work is well enough known to have a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sidewalk_Bleeding) so that should be simple enough.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't so simple, but I finally found the original citation!

Comment: Citations are on-topic on Writers, but not ELU.